# Unable to get response from server on port other than 80

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04, node.js

I'm currently using AWS EC2 instance 
My server built on node.js is running perfectly on port 80 and I get a response from API but if I switched to other port e.g. 8001 then I get no response from API. The ports are already configured which I want to use.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Are your Amazon security groups configured properly?

Comment: Yes, bro @Halfgaar

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? From where to where are you doing requests? Output of commands? etc. You can edit your question and include it.

Comment: Please edit your question to show more information. EG show a screenshot of your security group, and associated screenshots that show your instance has that security group attached. Show a ping, connection to port 80 working, the new / old configurations for port 80 / 8001, and then the connection to port 8001 failing. Basically - show us all your diagnostics.